# Deleting blank lines from Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Is there an easy way of removing blank lines from IPython notebook?

I have picked up a habit of blank lines from web development and my fingers tend to hit enter automatically. This makes IPython notebooks less(by taking too much of my 14" screen), not more readable in most cases.

I was wondering if there is a way of automatically remove blank lines from the notebooks.

In notebooks, I think preferred way of splitting the code is by placing each separate method to a different cell.

Is commonly accepted style guide for notebooks or does PEP 8 apply as it is?

**EDIT:** I think question 2, Is answered by IPython docs. https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Dev:-Coding-style

Comment: Empty cells are automatically created when running a cell by pressing 'alt enter'. This can be annoying. Running cells with 'shift enter' will not create empty cells.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are talking about deleting the empty line from jupyter notebook which opens in web browser then press Esc and D(keyboard key) 2 times.

You can also see all the keyboard shortcuts in the jupyter notebook file [image]

by clicking on the help and then from dropdown on keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 9):

Pressing Esc and D (2 times) will delete only blank lines starting from the beginning. It won't delete any lines which have some text or code.

Answer (score 5):

Pressing **Esc and D (2 times)** deletes the complete cell.

I guess the Question is about deleting the blank lines, unless the author interpretation of blank lines are blank cells.

If you came here looking for "How to delete a single line (whether code line or blank line) in a jupyter notebook cell"

**Ans:** ctrl-d (in Edit mode)

Answer (score 3):

Go to the required line and press: <kbd>ESC + D</kbd> (together ***twice***)

Answer (score 1):

Using a Mac:

- to forward delete a line from the curser use Fn + command + delete
- to backward delete a line from the curser use command + delete
- to delete a whole cell use Esc + (d twice)

These, and other shortcuts, can be found under the Help tab.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Ctrl+Backspace**  or **Ctrl+Delete**  both will delete blank lines.

Ctrl+Backspace can be used to delete whole text of line before cursor position.

Similarly Ctrl+Delete to delete text after cursor.

Answer (score 1):

If you came here looking for "How to delete a single line (whether code line or blank line) in a jupyter notebook cell"

ctrl-d (in Edit mode)

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is about deleting an empty new line of a cell.My solution is to write something in the line you want to delete, then go to the end of the line above it and press delete till the junk written in the line to be deleted is cleared.This deletes the empty new line as well.

Answer (score 0):

Select the row you want to delete and click the scissors icon highlighted in the below screenshot -
[image]