# How to automatically delete all blank lines in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

My Jupyter notebook gets filled with lots of blank lines. Currently I have to delete each line by clicking D+D, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42538052/827927). Is there a way to automatically remove all blank lines?

Answer (score 2):

`Esc D D` deletes the current cell, do you mean blank cells rather than blank lines?

If so, putting the following code into `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js` will add a button to the toolbar that will delete all blank cells

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
], function(Jupyter, events) {
    events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
        Jupyter.toolbar.add_buttons_group([
            {
                'label'   : 'delete all blank cells',
                'icon'    : 'fa-ban', // select your icon from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons
                'callback': function () {
                    var cells = Jupyter.notebook.get_cells();
                    cells.forEach(function(cell) {
                        if(cell.get_text() === "") {
                            var index = Jupyter.notebook.find_cell_index(cell);
                            Jupyter.notebook.delete_cell(index);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        ]);
    });
});
```

If you prefer a keyboard shortcut rather than button, use this (I've used `Alt-D`, but feel free to change it to whatever you want that isn't reserved by the notebook itself, you can check the existing keyboard shortcuts by clicking on Help > Keyboard Shortcuts):

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
], function(Jupyter, events) {
    events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
        Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('Alt-D', {
            help : 'delete blank cells',
            help_index : 'zz',
            handler : function (event) {
                var cells = Jupyter.notebook.get_cells();
                cells.forEach(function(cell) {
                    if(cell.get_text() === "") {
                        var index = Jupyter.notebook.find_cell_index(cell);
                        Jupyter.notebook.delete_cell(index);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }}
        );
    });
});
```

If you meant deleting blank lines within cells, it requires a little more work digging around into CodeMirror. Here's a button version:

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
], function(Jupyter, events) {
    events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
        Jupyter.toolbar.add_buttons_group([
            {
                'label'   : 'delete all blank lines',
                'icon'    : 'fa-ban', // select your icon from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons
                'callback': function () {
                    var cells = Jupyter.notebook.get_cells();
                    cells.forEach(function(cell) {
                        if(cell.cell_type === "code") {
                            var cm = cell.code_mirror;
                            cm.eachLine(function(line) {
                                if(!line.text) {
                                    var line_num = cm.getLineNumber(line);
                                    cm.setSelection({line: line_num - 1, ch: 255},{line: line_num + 1, ch: 0});
                                    cm.replaceSelection("");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
        ]);
```

And here's the keyboard shortcut version:

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
], function(Jupyter, events) {
    events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
        Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('Alt-C', {
            help : 'delete blank lines',
            help_index : 'zz',
            handler : function (event) {
                var cells = Jupyter.notebook.get_cells();
                cells.forEach(function(cell) {
                    if(cell.cell_type === "code") {
                        var cm = cell.code_mirror;
                        cm.eachLine(function(line) {
                            if(!line.text) {
                                var line_num = cm.getLineNumber(line);
                                cm.setSelection({line: line_num - 1, ch: 255},{line: line_num + 1, ch: 0});
                                cm.replaceSelection("");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }}
        );
    });
});
```

You might need to activate them a couple of times if you have multiple blank lines in a row - as when I tried using them they wouldn't remove all blank lines on the first pass but after 2 or 3 they removed everything.

Comment: I've attempted to use your shortcut to remove blank lines in a cell and I'm getting a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined, any ideas about this?  Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, it's saying that there's an undefined line. Even when I create a new blank code cell it still has the first line as defined. Are you running an old version of the notebook (as that would have an older version of CodeMirror)? Could you upload your notebook somewhere, or at least try and narrow down what cell is causing the issue? Because right now it works perfectly fine on my computer.

Comment: apologies, I'm not really sure why that was happening before but I got your extension to work and adapted it for single cells.  The only issue I have with it is I've found that if you rerun the blank line removal a few times on the same cell it will combine lines that don't have a blank line between them into one line.