# How can I delete several blank lines in a code in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a 15000 line code in Jupyter notebook. I wish to delete all the blank lines in code.
is there any shortcut in Jupyter notebook to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about deleting the empty line from jupyter notebook which opens in web browser then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> 2 times.

You can also see all the keyboard shortcuts in the jupyter notebook file
[image]

by clicking on the help and then from dropdown on keyboard shortcuts.

However, keep in mind that pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> (2 times) deletes the complete cell.

I guess the question is about deleting the blank lines, unless the author interpretation of blank lines are blank cells.

If you came here looking for "How to delete a single line (whether code line or blank line) in a jupyter notebook cell"

Ans: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> (in Edit mode)

Comment: Alternatively, the question is also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531056/deleting-blank-lines-from-jupyter-notebook